# Increment the element value in output based on the occurrence of an element in input

Tags: xml, xslt, position, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

Hello I am trying to write xslt where when similar input below is given I would need to get a desired output. if you observe the output has an id based on the occurrence of an element  in that xml. So far in my xslt i am doing it based on the position. but it breaks and restarts the count for every  from Input XML. Can this be achieved.

**update:**

Adding some more details to the input.  As you see I added  under  level and that should be populated on all of its respective  data

**Input XML**

```
<lines>
    <line>
      <po-num>text1</ponum>
        <accountings>
            <accounting>
                <account>
                    <seg1>value1</seg1>
                </account>
            </accounting>
            <accounting>
                <account>
                    <seg1>value2</seg1>
                </account>
            </accounting>
        </accountings>
    </line>
    <line>
       <po-num>text2</ponum>
        <accountings>
            <accounting>
                <account>
                    <seg1>value3</seg1>
                </account>
            </accounting>
        </accountings>
    </line>
    <line>
       <po-num>text3</ponum>
        <account>
            <seg1>value4</seg1>
        </account>
    </line>
</lines>
```

**Desired Output XML**

```
<Item>
    <id>1</id>
    <po-num>text1</ponum>
    <seg>value1</seg>
</Item>
<Item>
    <id>2</id>
    <po-num>text1</ponum>
    <seg>value2</seg>
</Item>
<Item>
    <id>3</id>
    <po-num>text2</ponum>
    <seg>value3</seg>
</Item>
<Item>
    <id>4</id>
     <po-num>text3</ponum>
    <seg>value4</seg>
</Item>
```

**XSLT**
I am using the xslt provided by Rupesh.

```
<?xml version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"></xsl:output>
<xsl:template match = "/">

    <xsl:for-each select="//account">
        <item>
            <id><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></id>
             <po-num><xsl:value-of select="../../../*:po-num"/></po-num>
            <seg><xsl:value-of select="./*:seg1"></xsl:value-of></seg>
        </item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What have  you tried? Sorry but StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and free code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Hello, I cannot share my actual code coz of various reasons, I will try create a sample XSLT code supporting above sample input. Its just huge piece of code. the above situation is small module in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:template match = "/">

        <xsl:for-each select="//seg1">
            <item>
                <id><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></id>
                <seg><xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of></seg>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you can see transformation at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/jyyiVhm

Comment: Thank you very much, This works like a charm and also optimizes my code.  Being new to XSLT I am missing some obvious things.